# How to keep checkbox and option on 1 only line

Tags: css, forms, joomla2.5

I'm using SimpleForms to publish a form on a Joomla 2.5 site.

The problem is that the checkbox and the options are on 2 different lines

The html generated is :

```
<form method="post" id="simpleForm2_142" name="simpleForm2_142" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="simpleForm">
<input type="hidden" name="moduleID" value="142" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="sendForm" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="230" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://xxx" autocomplete="off">
<style type="text/css">
form.simpleForm label{display:block;}
form.simpleForm label span{color:#ff0000;}
form.simpleForm input.inputtext{width:215px;}
form.simpleForm textarea.inputtext{width:215px;height:100px;}
form.simpleForm textarea.inputtext_small{width:215px;height:50px;}
</style>
<p><label for="sf2_142_nom">Nom <span>*</span></label> <input type="text" name="sf2_142_nom" id="sf2_142_nom" class="inputtext" value="" autocomplete="off"></p>
<p><label for="sf2_142_prnom">Prénom <span>*</span></label> <input type="text" name="sf2_142_prnom" id="sf2_142_prnom" class="inputtext" value="" autocomplete="off"></p>
<p><label for="sf2_142_adresse">Adresse <span>*</span></label> <textarea name="sf2_142_adresse" id="sf2_142_adresse" class="inputtext"></textarea></p>
<div class="chkbox"><label for="sf2_142_label">Label</label> 
<input type="checkbox" name="sf2_142_label[]" id="a7c1272bf8f1dfd06b1d0f85e31ac1b1" value="option1" autocomplete="off"> 
<label for="a7c1272bf8f1dfd06b1d0f85e31ac1b1">option1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="sf2_142_label[]" id="29def0c43615fa46358f41e04e9b07ee" value="option2" autocomplete="off"> 
<label for="29def0c43615fa46358f41e04e9b07ee">option2</label>
</div>
<p><input type="submit" value="Envoyer" autocomplete="off"></p>
</form>
```

I would like to use some css to make them keep on one only line

Any hint would be welcome !

EDIT :
I'm using simpleforms 2 for Joomla - here's the homepage of this extension :
http://allforjoomla.com/xmodules/mod-simpleform2

EDIT 2 :

Sorry I don't get it to make things clear when answering to your answers - as soon as I want to enter a new line it saves my answer - so my edit here :

Thanks for your answers, But if I do so I will get all this on one line :

```
Label <checkbox> option1 <checkbox> option2
```

I want to get :

```
Label 
<checkbox> option1 
<checkbox> option2
```

EDIT 3 :

Its Better with :

```
form.simpleForm label:first-child { display: block; }
```

But I get :

```
Label 
<checkbox> option1 <checkbox> option2
```

And this is what I try to get :

```
Label 
<checkbox> option1 
<checkbox> option2
```

Comment: Please put your question title in English! Merci beaucoup.

Comment: There is not enough relevant code here to help you.  Please provide all the HTML and CSS to demonstrate the problem, but without anything irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove this line:

```
form.simpleForm label {
    display: block;
}
```

Or, if you want to keep the first label (as mentioned in the note below) as a block element, do this instead:

```
form.simpleForm label:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, But if I do so I will get all this on one line :

    Label <checkbox> option1 <checkbox> option2

I want to get :

    Label 
    <checkbox> option1 
    <checkbox> option2

Sorry I don't get it to make things clear on this form - as soon as I want to enter a new line it saves my answer

Comment: O, right. Really, you don't need that first label (it has no purpose, as each check box has a label). But if you do want to keep it, then use the modified code I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Making element inline will your issue.

```
form.simpleForm label, form.simpleForm div.chkbox input{ display:inline !important}
```